# Storing python spark data into a list and passing as parameter

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a python spark file :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import json

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Hello") \
    .config("World") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

ratings = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("transactions.json").map(lambda l: json.loads(l))
)



ratings.registerTempTable("ratings")

final_df = sqlContext.sql("select * from ratings");
final_df.show(20,False)
```

This generates the output:

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+
|click_id|         created_at|          ip|product_id|product_price|user_id|
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+
|     123|2016-10-03 12:50:33| 10.10.10.10|     98373|        220.5|      1|
|     124|2017-02-03 11:51:33| 10.13.10.10|     97373|        320.5|      1|
|     125|2017-10-03 12:52:33| 192.168.2.1|     96373|         20.5|      1|
|     126|2017-10-03 13:50:33|172.16.11.10|     88373|        220.5|      2|
|     127|2017-10-03 13:51:33| 10.12.15.15|     87373|        320.5|      2|
|     128|2017-10-03 13:52:33|192.168.1.10|     86373|         20.5|      2|
|     129|2017-08-03 14:50:33| 10.13.10.10|     78373|        220.5|      3|
|     130|2017-10-03 14:51:33| 12.168.1.60|     77373|        320.5|      3|
|     131|2017-10-03 14:52:33| 10.10.30.30|     76373|         20.5|      3|
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

I want to store only the IP column values into  list so as to pass each of those values as a parameter to a function called `def find_ip_city(ip_address)` which returns the city of the IP.

Is there a way in spark to store the data frame into list and pass each value of the list as a parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Think you can use your function find_ip_city(ip_address) as UDF and pass on the column values directly rather than collecting them as list. Please find pseudo-code,

```
def find_ip_city(ip_address):
    pass

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
cityUDF = udf(find_ip_city,StringType())

final_df.withColumn('city',cityUDF(final_df['ip'])).show()
```

Hope this helps.!